# Hive + HBase Integration: Data Showing up in HBASE when queried, Not showing up in HIVE

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase

In an attempt to integrate hive with HBASE I have created the table below from hive.  It was created successfully and I can access the table directly from HIVE and HBASE.

The problem is when I insert overwrite data into the table from HIVE, I am only seeing the data appear in HBASE.  When I do a SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T_PONNMS_ONT_4 from Hive it returns 0.  Yet when I query a record count from HBASE for the same table all 50 million records appear.  Is there any reason why this is the case?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS T_PONNMS_ONT_4
(
TRANSACTIONORIGIN STRING,
TRANSACTIONID INT,
TRANSACTIONTIME STRING,
TRANSACTIONTYPE STRING,
ONT_UNIQUEID STRING,
ONT_SHELFNUM STRING,
ONTNUM STRING,
ONT_SERIALNUM STRING,
ONT_VENDOR STRING,
ONT_MODEL STRING,
ONT_STATUS STRING)
PARTITIONED BY (FILENAME STRING, TRANSACTION_DATE STRING)
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('hbase.columns.mapping' = 'cf:TRANSACTIONORIGIN,
                                                 cf:TRANSACTIONID,
                                                 cf:TRANSACTIONTIME,
                                                 cf:TRANSACTIONTYPE,
                                                 :key,
                                                 cf:ONT_SHELFNUM,
                                                 cf:ONTNUM,
                                                 cf:ONT_SERIALNUM,
                                                 cf:ONT_VENDOR,
                                                 cf:ONT_MODEL,
                                                 cf:ONT_STATUS')
TBLPROPERTIES ('hbase.table.name' = 'T_PONNMS_ONT_4');
```

INSERT DATA INTO HBASE TABLE THROUGH HIVE

```
--Data is properly loaded into HBASE table T_PONNMS_ONT_4
    INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE T_PONNMS_ONT_4 PARTITION (FILENAME, TRANSACTION_DATE) SELECT * FROM T_PONNMS_ONT;
```

HIVE> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T_PONNMS_4;
OK
0
Time Taken 0.241

HBASE> count 'T_PONNMS_ONT_4'
Returns 50 million

Comment: You are following correct way.Check hive log if anything going wrong.

Comment: Checked the hive long nothing seems to be irregular.  I am assuming it may be an issue with the HIVE config settings as the data is clearly loaded, its just that HIVE is not pointing to any data.  Hence why I can see the table but it if unable to pull data from HIVE.